# IOS Simulators shows a black screen after I installed xCode 10 (I have mac that is from 2011)

Tags: ios, xcode

Ever since I tried to install and text XCode 10 my iPad simulators has a black screen.
I have tried to run this command defaults write com.apple.CoreSimulator.IndigoFramebufferServices FramebufferRendererHint 3
but it is still not working short of reinstalling everything I don't know what to do.

Comment: I saw this problem in early versions of Xcode 10 but it was fixed in later versions.

Comment: The funny thing is that it is only my IOS 11 simulators that has the problem IOS 10 is OK

Comment: Yes and only iPad, I know

Comment: I'm having the same issue. What kind of machine are you running? I'm using a 2010 iMac

Comment: Yep I am running a mid 2010 iMac

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this has been fixed in Xcode 10.1 beta 3, at least for me.